# Almacenar datos en una tabla intermedia en SQL Server, desde Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de almacenar los datos que tengo en un ComboBox a mi base de datos (Sql Server).

Esta es la cuestión: tengo dos tablas principales (socios y clubes) y para relacionar estas dos tablas he creado la tabla intermedia (sociosclubes).

Ahora, desde Visual Studio estoy tratando de almacenar los datos y no puedo. En el formulario de socios tengo tres ComboBox en dónde muestro los clubes.

¿Cómo guardo la información de estos ComboBox en la base de datos?, teniendo en cuenta que se almacena en dos tablas diferentes (socios y sociosclubes), dónde sociosclubes solo almacena las llaves foráneas de las tablas (socios y clubes).

A continuación el diseño de mi formulario:

[image: formulario]

Si alguien puede ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: Hola, soy un usuario que también hace preguntas y por experiencia te comento que también puedes mostrar el código que ya tienes para que en base a ese código se te pueda ayudar. así como también si deseas guardar con un sp o con entity

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Un insert por cada valor seleccionado en los combos de club.

Comment: Sería valioso agregar un código de ejemplo que muestre el cómo se hace.